# Facing issue while applying css transform properties to DOM object using multiple css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Facing issue while applying css tranform properties to DOM object using multiple css classes</title>
    <!-- PUT A PATH OF JQUERY LIBRARY -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var flag = true;
        setInterval(function () {
            if (flag) {
                flag = false;
                $("#spelling_game_score_box_score").addClass("active_score");
            }
            else {
                flag = true;
                $("#spelling_game_score_box_score").removeClass("active_score");
            }
        },2000);
    }
</script>
<style>
    #spelling_game_score_box_score {
        position:absolute;
        top:200px;
        left:200px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        transform: rotate(-30deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
        font-size: 36px;
        background-color: orange;
    }
    .active_score {
        transform: scale(2);
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
        -moz-transform: scale(2);
        -ms-transform: scale(2);
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="spelling_game_score_box_score">100</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I run the code I can not find `scale()` effect after interval of 2000 ms. But when I comment following css under `#spelling_game_score_box_score` selector

```
/*transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);*/
```

I can have scale effect but can not find rotate effect. 
I want to know that is there some sub properties for css tranform like border has `border-color`, `border-style` etc. so I can have some solution regarding the problem.
Please help me if you have some idea about it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. [CSS Specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)
2. transform css code

First, you use id to specify the transform functions:

```
#spelling_game_score_box_score {
    ...
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    ...
}
```

Then, you try to override it by specifying a class:

```
.active_score {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

which wouldn't work because of the CSS specificity problem.

You can solve this by making it more specific:

```
#spelling_game_score_box_score.active_score {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

But then we come to the second problem where `transform: scale(2);` overrides the original transformation.

To solve this you can use both `rotate` and `scale` in the same transformation.

```
#spelling_game_score_box_score.active_score {
    transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(2);
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uopfapd3/

Comment: I need to apply .active_score on multiple location so rotate effect will be applied on every dom where i apply .active_score class. So there will be another issue i will face.

Comment: Then I would suggest that instead of using an id earlier, you use another class. e.g. `.game_score_box_score`